Fill a 2-D array of integer using double pointer and scanf()
When I run the test, it offers to fill the 2-D array in a loop (indefinitely).
void assign(int** mat, int N, int M) 
{ 
    int *p;
    for (p = &mat[0][0] ; p <= &mat[N-1][M-1] ; p++)
    { 
        printf("Give an integer number : ");
        scanf("%d", &*p) ;
    }
}

Main program:
int main(){//1- Dynamically allocate memory for array 2-D using double pointer
const int N=4;  //#define N 4
const int M=4;  //#define M 3
int **p = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * N);  

if (p == NULL)
{
    printf("No allocated memory\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    p[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * M);   

    if (p[i] == NULL)
    {
        printf("No allocated memory\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

assign(p, N, M);
Display(p, N, M);


return 0;}


int** mat is not a int mat[N][M].

int ** "jagged array" and int [N][M] "rectangle array" have a different memory layout. You declare as one and the loop traverses as the other one. Use two nested loops with indexes instead.

... or declare the function parameter with appropriate type, if a "rectangle array" is what you're actually trying to pass.

You cannot traverse an array like that with a single pointer. There is absolutely no guarantee whatsoever that pointer comparison will work across rows.

Don't compare addresses like that p <= &mat[N-1][M-1], instead of address, compare index of the array

You don't have a 2d array of integers.
You don't have a 1d array of integers.
You have a 1d array of pointers to 1d arrays of ints, for a total of N+1 1d arrays.
But then you write for (p = &mat[0][0] ; p <= &mat[N-1][M-1] ; p++) as if you have just one array. That won't work. You can't compare pointers to elements of different arrays.
Fixed:
void assign( int **mat, int n, int m ) {
   for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
      for ( int j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
         printf( "Give an integer: " );
         scanf( "%d", &mat[ i ][ j ] );
      }
   }
}

Using advancing pointers (as requested, though far less readable):
void assign( int **mat, int n, int m ) {

   int **p = mat;
   for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {

      int *q = *p;
      for ( int j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
         printf( "Give an integer: " );
         scanf( "%d", q );
         ++q;
      }

      ++p;
   }
}

With pointer comparisons:
void assign( int **mat, int n, int m ) {
   int **p = mat;
   int **p_end = p + n;
   for ( ; p < p_end; ++p ) {
      int *q = *p;
      int *q_end = q + m;
      for ( ; q < q_end; ++q ) {
         printf( "Give an integer: " );
         scanf( "%d", q );
      }
   }
}

In all cases, the outer loop iterates over the array of pointers, and the inner loop iterates over one of the array of ints.

Thanks to everyone, especially ikegami, this is exactly what I wanted to do.

I'm not quit sure why you used pointer on the for loop, but i assume your trying to take inputs for each element in a 2-d array, so do this. notice that
I'm using a pointer which is storing the address of each element, and storing
the value at each memory location. hope this helps!
void assign(int **mat, int n, int m)   {
    int i, j;
    int *p
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  
     {
         for (j = 0; j < m; j++) 
         {
              p = &mat[i][j];
              printf("Give an integer: ");
              scanf("%d", p);
          }
     }
}


I don't want to use indexes (i, j) but only a pointer to write (or browse) a 2-D array.

okay how about this p = ((mat + i) + j).

((mat + i) + j) is just a less readable way of writing &mat[i][j]. There are no benefits with the former style what-so-ever.

@Aventeesh ( ( mat + i ) + j ) is wrong.

@Lundin, &mat[i][j] is ( *( mat + i ) + j ), not ( ( mat + i ) + j ).

@hogar, &mat[ i ][ j ] is 100% equivalent to for &*( *( mat + i ) + j ), which simplifies to *( mat + i ) + j. But also, see my answer.
